# Video Output as iSight Input

Tags: macbook-pro, skype, webcam

I'd like to be able to display videos and pictures through my MacBook Pro's webcam on Skype and other online chat sites. I previously used programs such as ManyCam to emulate a webcam, however, many online sites no longer accept external video inputs - only iSight (built-in or external).

Is there any way to be able to send the output from ManyCam to the input of iSight? This way, I can still display videos on sites which only allow iSight, as the video will technically be coming from an iSight cam.

Comment: It's very unlikely that any site only accept iSight; I suspect they only allow specific types of cameras. Can you give an example website? And have you tried any other video sources (USB, FW, or Thunderbolt based)?

Answer (score 1):

[Camtwist](http://camtwiststudio.com) works for such things
(haven't yet personally tested it in mavericks)