# How to combine two live video feeds with picture in picture

Tags: macos, video, camera, webcam, video-capture

Is it possible to combine the feeds from a USB webcam / IP video stream (iPad) and the built-in iSight camera on my MacBook Pro (early 2011) running Yosemite into one video feed for use in, for example, Skype, but also other applications. My use case is to record myself playing guitar from two angles simultaneously.

Comment: Does the answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/video-output-as-isight-input?rq=1 help?

Comment: I tried camtwist but its not working for me - the two video streams are not available at the same time using PIP. Maybe because I am using a very old USB webcam, not sure.

Comment: Doing this for a live feed as in Skype is very different from doing it for a recording. If you're comfortable with editing your video later, a capable video editing program should easily allow you to put one video above another. Maybe even iMovie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Livestream** app for OS X and iOS.

There are maybe standalone apps, but I figured out fairly simple way to do this.

The setup:

1. Your Mac will be handling the image processing using [Livestream's Producer](https://livestream.com/producer) app
2. Your iPad will be just sending video to your Mac throught [Livestream's App for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/livestream/id493086499).
3. Start the stream on your iPad
4. Open your iPad's stream in browser on your Mac (and make it fullscreen and mute audio)
5. Start stream on your Mac.

You will have nice ability to choose source of video - Webcam or ScreenShare (in this case your iPad stream) or both using 2D or 3D effect as show on the image bellow.

[image]

P.S. You can probably do the same using Google Hangouts call, but you will not have control over the image.